# Coldfusion How can i detect duplicate variable in array

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, cfml, coldfusion-2016

There is a loop I pulled from the database with `cfloop`. After transferring this loop to arrays, I want to increase the number of stocks if the same array exists.

```
<cfoutput query="getStocks">
    <cfif #CurrentRow# lt 5> 
        <cfscript>
            c=#CurrentRow#;
            if (c==1){
                arr[c]['stok_kod']='#STOCK_CODE#';
                arr[c]['lot']='#LOT_NO#';
                arr[c]['stok']=#STOK_MIKTARI#;
                arr[c]['depo']='#DEPO#';
                arr[c]['isim']='#PRODUCT_NAME#';
                arr[c]['skt']='#GET_SKT.DELIVER_DATE#';
            }
            for (i=1; i <= arrayLen(#arr#);i++) {
                if (arr[i]['stok_kod'] eq '#STOCK_CODE#' ){
                    arr[i]['stok']+=#STOK_MIKTARI#;
                }else{
                    arr[c]['stok_kod']='#STOCK_CODE#';
                    arr[c]['lot']='#LOT_NO#';
                    arr[c]['stok']=#STOK_MIKTARI#;
                    arr[c]['depo']='#DEPO#';
                    arr[c]['isim']='#PRODUCT_NAME#';
                    arr[c]['skt']='#GET_SKT.DELIVER_DATE#';
                }
            }
        </cfscript>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

[image]

How can I detect those with the same stock code?

Comment: You could forget about the arrays and use `Query of Queries` to determine which stock codes appear more than once.

Comment: You could use ArrayFind/FindNoCase with a closure function, but seems a little heavyweight.  What about doing the aggregation in SQL? What's your dbms and sql query?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **query of queries** method with `GROUP BY` function

Here is the example how it works.

```
<cfscript>
    getStocks = queryNew("stok_kod,stok", "varchar,integer");
    queryAddRow(getStocks);
    querySetCell(getStocks, "stok_kod", "1234");
    querySetCell(getStocks, "stok", "-10");
    queryAddRow(getStocks);
    querySetCell(getStocks, "stok_kod", "5678");
    querySetCell(getStocks, "stok", "10");
    queryAddRow(getStocks);
    querySetCell(getStocks, "stok_kod", "1234");
    querySetCell(getStocks, "stok", "30");
</cfscript>

<cfquery name="newQuery" dbtype="query">
  SELECT stok_kod, SUM(stok) as stok
  FROM getStocks
  GROUP BY stok_kod
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#newQuery#">
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Result output]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you have one variable that will have the list of your **distinct** stock codes.

Example: `<cfset lst_stok_kod = "a,b,c,d">` Perhaps from your SQL query.

After that, you could use the `ArrayFindNoCase` function to check if your array has that stock code present or not. If you find it more than once, you increase the number of stocks each time.